# Redirect(relativeUrl) redirecting to wrong path in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

In the usual `AccountController` in my MVC3 app, if `returnUrl` is set (in my case, I set it manually), it will call `Redirect(returnUrl)`.

Assume my return URL is `/Admin/HealthCheck` (which it really is). When I'm debugging, I get a URL like `http://localhost:3279/Admin/HealthCheck` from the redirect call.

Then, I deployed my app to `http://localhost/Test`. In this case, `Redirect(returnUrl)` redirects me to `http://localhost/Admin/HealthCheck` and *not* the expected `http://localhost/Test/Admin/HealthCheck`.

What's going on here? How do I fix this (if it is fixable)?

Below is a snippet from the (standard) MVC3 AccountController; you can see where I get the return URL from the query string (eg. `http://localhost/Test/LogOn?ReturnUrl=/Admin/HealthCheck`, albeit URL encoded).

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    returnUrl = Request.Params["ReturnUrl"];

                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (in my case, I set it manually)

You haven't actually shown how this manual setting happens, but if you have hardcoded an url such as `/Admin/HealthCheck` instead of using an url helper to generate this url such as `Url.Action("HealthCheck", "Admin")` don't expect miracles to happen.

Your `LogOn` is fine. It does what it is supposed to do => it redirects to the url that is passed as argument. Your problem lies in the way you are setting this url.

Conclusion: in an ASP.NET MVC application always use url helpers when dealing with urls. Never hardcode them.

Comment: My case is redirecting to a protected page after log in. So the user attempts to access a protected page, gets the login page, and should be redirected back. How can I do that? It sounds like your approach would be to store the controller name, action name, and other parameters and use that in `Url.Action`. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @ashes999, if the user tries to access a protected page, he types this page address in the address bar, doesn't he? And when your application is deployed in IIS he types `/Test/Admin/HealthCheck` instead of `/Admin/HealthCheck`, doesn't he? Because if he typed `/Admin/HealthCheck` he would have gotten a 404 from IIS, wouldn't he? In this case everything works as expected. I don't understand what your problem is actually.

Answer (score 1):

For your `Test` URL, you would have to set your `ReturnUrl` to be `Test/Admin/HealthCheck`.

Note the [MSDN Reference on `Controller.Redirect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect.aspx):

> Creates a `RedirectResult` object that redirects to the specified URL.

In other words, if you put `"/Admin/HealthCheck"` as your parameter, that is exactly where the redirect will be.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, since in IIS, the root is /Test. Maybe it's just me, but relative URLs are supposed to be relative to the application root URL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        string refUri = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Redirect(refUri + "#/account/login");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your end domain is going to be `www.domain.com/Test/Admin/HealthCheck` you may want to change the virtual directory for your project so that you dont have to make changes in the URL when switching between localhost and your actual server.

If you are using Visual Studio, you can change the virtual path assigned to your project by clicking on the project in the solution explorer and hitting F4. This will display the project properties window which has an option to change the virtual path. In your case, you would want to change it to `/Test`. You will still have to change your urls to contain the `/Test` though.

Although just as Darin pointed out, you should use the url helpers.

Comment: See my comment to his answer.